# Filter on a view is applied to filters excluded in a view

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, view

I have a table that can have JSON data in a column. I added a calculated column to the table with the `ISJSON()` function to mark any rows that do not contain valid JSON data

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, Content NVARCHAR(MAX), IsJsonRecord AS ISJSON(Content))
GO
INSERT INTO tbl1 (Content) VALUES ('a'), ('{"name":"asd"}')
GO
```

Now I have a view that parses the JSON data out to more readable formats such as

```
CREATE VIEW vw1
AS
SELECT Id,
    JSON_VALUE(Content, '$."name"') AS Name
FROM tbl1
WHERE IsJsonRecord > 0
```

The WHERE clause works as expected when I select from the view.

```
SELECT *
FROM vw1
```

When I query the view with an additional where clause I get an error due to malformed JSON data (as below).

```
SELECT *
FROM vw1
WHERE [Name] LIKE '%a%'
```

It seems like the query WHERE clause is applied to rows that do not conform to the WHERE clause already specified in the view.

Is this the expected behavior?

I understand that the view is "optimized away", but I was expecting the query optimizer to apply filters to distinct fields before it applied filters that requires functions to operate on data. I would think that logic could have performance benefits in some scenarios.

I'm not too sure what to do to accommodate the WHERE clause on the view. My actual case is much more complex than the example, and I'm not sure that I can test each column in the view with a `CASE` statement over the `JSON_VALUE` statement.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like odd behavior. The error goes away if you replace `json_value(...)` with a `cross apply openjson(...) with (...)` construct but I would not have expected the error in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, no you cannot tell the compiler in which order to do the filters, although there are tricks you can do which usually force it to do so.

The problem is that your query is effectively compiled like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Id,
        JSON_VALUE(Content, '$."name"') AS Name
    FROM tbl1
    WHERE IsJsonRecord > 0
) vw1
WHERE [Name] LIKE '%a%'
```

Which is then trivially optimized to:

```sql
SELECT Id,
    JSON_VALUE(Content, '$."name"') AS Name
FROM tbl1
WHERE IsJsonRecord > 0 AND [Name] LIKE '%a%'
```

At this point the compiler will make a decision as to which part to evaluate first. For whatever reason, it has chosen to do the `LIKE` first, this may be due to a good index.

You have a number of solutions:

- Use `CASE`, which is guaranteed (except in certain situations) to be evaluated in order

```sql
SELECT Id,
    JSON_VALUE(Content, '$."name"') AS Name
FROM tbl1
WHERE CASE WHEN IsJsonRecord > 0 THEN CASE WHEN [Name] LIKE '%a%' THEN 1 END END = 1
```

- Add an index on the persisted column, either with the column as the leading key, or a filtered index `IsJsonRecord > 0`.
  This is not guaranteed to always work, but it usually does. Make sure to include all columns necessary.
- A variation on the above is to add a clustered index to the view. There are many restrictions on doing this, but it can work very well. Make sure to add `WITH (NOEXPAND)` hint to the query.
- A more guaranteed option is to add a `TOP` to the view.
  This forces the compiler to ensure that `IsJsonRecord > 0` is logically evaluated first, which nearly always means it will be physically executed first.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (9223372036854775807) *
    FROM vw1
) vw1
WHERE [Name] LIKE '%a%'
```

Comment: Thanks for a great response, I will have to experiment. Another way I found is below. Problem is my views are being used for other things, so I need to be sure none of this breaks those cases. ALTER   VIEW [dbo].[vw1]
AS
SELECT Id,
 CASE WHEN IsJsonRecord = 0 THEN NULL ELSE  JSON_VALUE(Content, '$."name"') END AS Name
FROM tbl1
WHERE IsJsonRecord > 0
GO